# Why can't Padrino find my rake tasks?

Tags: ruby, rake, bundler, gemfile, padrino

I just upgraded Padrino from version 0.10.5 to 0.12.1 and now none of my Rake tasks work anymore.

A simple case I just added:

```
# PROJECT_ROOT/lib/tasks/example_task.rake
task :example_task do
  puts "Is this working?"
end
```

Running `rake example_task` gives:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'example_task'
```

Running `padrino rake example_task` gives:

```
=> Executing Rake example_task ...
/Users/george/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]': Don't know how to build task 'example_task' (RuntimeError)
```

Padrino's [docs](http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/rake-tasks) say that Padrino should automatically detect any `*.rake` files in `lib/tasks`, and these worked before I upgraded Padrino. What's the problem?

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.0'

gem 'rake'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'rack_hoptoad', require: 'rack/hoptoad'

gem 'haml'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'mongo'
gem 'mongoid', '~> 3.1.6'
gem 'httparty'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'fabrication', '~> 1.3.1'
  gem 'zippy'
  gem 'rubyzip', '~> 0.9.9'
end

group :test do
  gem 'mocha', '~> 0.10.4'
  gem 'rspec', '~> 2.8.0'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 1.1.2'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'cucumber', '~> 1.1.8'
end

gem 'tilt', '~> 1.4.1'
gem 'padrino', '~> 0.12.1'
gem 'padrino-cookies', '~> 0.1.2'
```

According to `bundle show rake`, I'm using rake version 10.3.1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the output of `rake -T` and `padrino rake -T` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was a waste of a bounty.

I [opened an issue on Github](https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/issues/1664) and got an answer there. I needed to make the following changes to the top of `config/boot.rb`... (this is taken from the output of `git diff`, so note that lines which start with `-` were removed and lines which start with `+` were added.)

```
-begin
-  # Require the preresolved locked set of gems.
-  require File.expand_path('../../.bundle/environment', __FILE__)
-rescue LoadError
-  # Fallback on doing the resolve at runtime.
-  require 'rubygems'
-  require 'bundler'
-  Bundler.setup
-end
-
+require 'rubygems' unless defined?(Gem)
+require 'bundler/setup'
```

And add these lines to my `Rakefile`:

```
+require 'bundler/setup'
+require 'padrino-core/cli/rake'
+
+PadrinoTasks.use(:database)
+PadrinoTasks.use(:mongoid)
+PadrinoTasks.init
```

Now my rake tasks work as normal. Yay!

Comment: (Worth noting for any future Googlers... you obviously don't want to add the line `PadrinoTasks.use(:mongoid)` if you're not using Mongoid for your DB!)

Comment: as of padrino 0.14, one way for me to add gems based tasks is to load gem in Rakefile, example: require 'padrino/sprocket'

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern and it will work with new version of Padrino without any core changes:

```
# ./lib/tasks/seed_fonts.rake
namespace :fonts do

  desc "Seen the fonts into database table db.fonts"
  task :seed_fonts => :environment do

      # Do your thing ...

  end

end
```